# Каковы аналоги функций ord и chr Python для Rust (если есть)?

Tags: python, алгоритм, rust

Rust.
Как вернуть код символа от числа и как получить кодовое число от символа? Чтобы диапазон символов был до 1 000 000?

```
println!("{}", 244 as char);
```

Так работает, но если диапазон больше 255 ошибка, тут нужно поставить нужный тип данных возможно, который имеет диапазон больше 255, но какой я без понятия....либо может есть аналоги простых функций `ord()`, `chr()` Питона?

Comment: Э? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.from_u32

Answer (score 1):

```
let c = std::char::from_u32(1000000).unwrap();

println!("{}", c);
println!("{}", c as u32);
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=86d9eb0a80a74f6af2f41765d9d0843b)

Comment: Вместо `1000000` лучше смотрится `0x1F603`